# Hide third child div in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to hide third child div in jQuery , but its hide first child div subchild.

I am trying with below code :-

Html :-

```
<div id="parent-1">
    <div id="child-1" class="child">CHILD 1
       <div id="sub-child-1" class="subchild">SUB CHILD 1</div>
       <div id="sub-child-2" class="subchild">SUB CHILD 2</div>
       <div id="sub-child-3" class="subchild">SUB CHILD 3</div>
    </div>
    <div id="child-2" class="child">CHILD 2</div>
    <div id="child-3" class="child">CHILD 3</div>
</div>
```

Jquery :-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('div#parent-1 div:eq(2)').css("display", "none");
});
```

I need to hide `child-3` here. but it is hiding `sub-child-3`.

here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roopendra/uBn9a/2/)

Any suggestion??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use tagNames in front of an `id` selector - it causes jQuery to do more work than needed. Just use `#parent-1`

Comment: @lan : thanks for suggestion . I will take care in my code.

Comment: You can directly use the ID [child-3] to hide the div.

Comment: I know it is simple @ janak shah but my requirement is nothing like that. Thnks man for suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('div#parent-1 > div:eq(2)').css("display", "none");
});
```

The `>` does it all.

Comment: See my answer AND jsPerf test to compare.

Comment: @Roopendra: that's the SLOWEST option and with the slowest performance of all answers; see my answer with jsPerf test. This shouldn't be the accepted answer.

Comment: @frenchie Nowhere in the OP does it ask for the "fastest". There are **many** ways to accomplish something in jQuery. Some people like using selectors, some people like using methods. If you're actually comparing performance for something like this, you're not coding right

Comment: That's the most efficient answer: $('#parent-1').find('.child').eq(2).css('display','none'); just try it out in jsPerf.

Comment: @frenchie : thanks for valuable information regarding performance. Can i do it without using css `find(.child)`?.

Comment: Using .find() is the fastest and best way to do it. Here's John Resig explaining why: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LmsWA2FYdIE

Comment: I never claimed my solution was the fastest. I don't know who downvoted me, but downvoting for a perfectly valid solution is a bit childish.

Comment: @JNDPNT It was frenchie, it happened right after they commented. It's funny to me - I don't remember the answers on StackOverflow requiring the fastest option...

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#parent-1 .child').eq(2).css("display", "none");
});
```

or you can use like

```
$('#parent-1 > div:eq(2)').css("display", "none");
```

that represents the relative childs of the 'parent-1'

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (*Updated*)

```
$('#parent-1').children('div').eq(2).hide();
```

**or**

```
$('#parent-1 > div').eq(2).hide();
```

`.hide()` will work same as `display : none;`

Later you can use `.show()` to display the element again. (if you want to).

Answer (score 0):

very simply do it with css only:

```
#child-3{
   display:none;
}
```

Comment: My case is different. that's why i asked using Jquery :). thanks

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
$('#child-3',$('#parent-1')).hide();
```

Comment: Hey Sumit thanks for your answer. In my case id is not fixed that's why I can't give id directly.

Comment: you wrote third child, as far as dynamic selection is concerned, you will have to provide exact event invoker through which one can determine the relation with this 3rd child div.